Let $A$ and $B$ be two points on the sphere centered at the origin. How can one find all rotations that bring $A$ to $B$?
Let $A$ and $B$ be two points on the sphere centered at the origin. How can one find all rotations that bring $A$ to $B$? It's clear that any two such rotations differ by a rotation around the axis through the origin and $B$ (let denote this axis $a_{OB}$), that is, if $R_1$ and $R_2$ brings $A$ to $B$ then $R_2=R_{OB}\circ R_1$ where $R_{OB}$ is a rotation around $a_{OB}$. Given $R_1$, what is the easiest way to find all axes for all $R_2=R_{OB}\circ R_1$ belonging to all $R_{OB}$?

Your last question is a bit unclear. Are you looking at how to construct all possible $R_{OB}$?

You can get some insight into this at the Wikipedia plot summary for the (complex) Hopf fibration. Some of the "Definition and Construction" section deals with this. Each fiber represents all the rotations that take a given point $A$ to some point $B$. But you don't really need to know about fiber bundles to understand the material there that you want.

@HackR No, it's trivial, since given the axis $a_{OB}$, all $R_{oB}$ differ only in the angle. I want to find all axis of $R_{OB}\circ R_1$ where the angle of $R_{OB}$ varies. In the case of angle = $0$, this axis is the axis of $R_1$.

Isn't that simply $\cos(\phi)\vec v+\sin(\phi)B$ where $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ and $\vec v$ is the axis of $R_1$?

If $R$ is any rotation that takes $A$ to $B$, the axis of rotation of $R$ must intersect the sphere at a point equidistant from $A$ and $B$. Moreover, any point equidistant from $A$ and $B$ lies on the axis of a rotation that takes $A$ to $B$.
The set of such axes is the set of axes that lie in a plane orthogonal to the line through $A$ and $B$.
